# Who or what do you read the "among others" refers to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Below is a quote from the book I explained in [one of my recent postings](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/257884/with-no-jobs-bobby-would-be-happy-and-with-no-jobs-would-bobby-be-happy-wh) on this StackExchange website.

> George Bush's victory in the 2000 presidential election was an
> extremely narrow one, with a controversy over who won Florida's
> electoral votes, ***among others***.

Who or what do you read the "among others" refers to in this context?

Comment: "Among other controversies" would be my guess. No other possibility seems to make much sense.

Comment: @Maciej Stachowski: Thanks. If that is the case, do we need the comma right before "*among others*"? Since the phrase "*with a controversy over who won Florida's electoral votes*" is written parenthetically, I thought that "*among others*" was linked with the part coming before the first comma.